# Using previous data of a model in the creation view class to store in other model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm working on an app, where I store information about fuel consumption of vehicles, the goal is every time a vehicle refuels to calculate the consumption per km of fuel and storing it.
my models are:

```py
class Refuel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name=_("responsable_user"), default=1)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey("vehicle.Vehicle", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    gaz_station = models.ForeignKey(
        GazStation, related_name=_("Refuel_Station"), blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    odometer_reading = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Compteur KM"), blank=True, null=True)
    snitch = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Mouchard KM"), blank=True, null=True)
    fuel_quantity = models.DecimalField(_("Quantitée en Litres"), max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    fuel_unit_price = models.DecimalField(_("Prix en DH"), max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    note = models.CharField(_("Remarque"), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Created at"), auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Updated at"), auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    @property
    def total_price(self):
        total_price = self.fuel_quantity * self.fuel_unit_price
        return total_price

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["gaz_station", "-created_at"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vehicle.serie


class FuelConsumption(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey("vehicle.Vehicle", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    gaz_station = models.ForeignKey(
        GazStation, related_name=_("Station_consuption"), blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    Controlor_id = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        limit_choices_to={"is_controlor": True, "is_active": True},
    )
    driver = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name=_("Vehicle_Driver_consuption"), blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    consumption = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Created at"), auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Updated at"), auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["vehicle", "-created_at"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vehicle.serie
```

I have a view for Refuel model, where I want if possible to make calculation of the consumption of fuel per km by calling the last object for the vehicle and get the odometer and calculate the distance and divide the previous refuel quantity by this distance and store it.
The view I Have is:

```py
class RefuelCreationView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Refuel
    form_class = RefuelCreationForm
    template_name = "refuel/refuel_form.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("refuel:controlor-refuel-list")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user_id = self.request.user.id
        form.instance.gaz_station = GazStation.objects.get(Controlor_id=self.request.user.id)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_active and self.request.user.is_controlor
```

It's my first project after learning Django by working on tutorial and I hope to get help doing this.

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track. What is your actual question?

Comment: I solved the problem, I get the last record for every vehicle in the ''form_valid'' before and made the calcule I wanted before saving the new refuel data. I'm adding the solution below if you have any advise it'll be welcome

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it, the view I used is :

```py
class RefuelCreationView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Refuel
    form_class = RefuelCreationForm
    template_name = "refuel/refuel_form.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("refuel:controlor-refuel-list")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user_id = self.request.user.id
        form.instance.gaz_station = GazStation.objects.get(Controlor_id=self.request.user.id)
        old_refuel_data = Refuel.objects.order_by().distinct("vehicle")
        for refuel in old_refuel_data:
            if refuel.vehicle == form.instance.vehicle and form.instance.odometer_reading:
                consumption = (refuel.fuel_quantity / (form.instance.odometer_reading - refuel.odometer_reading)) * 100
                FuelConsumption.objects.create(
                    vehicle=refuel.vehicle,
                    gaz_station=form.instance.gaz_station,
                    Controlor_id=self.request.user,
                    driver=refuel.vehicle.driver,
                    consumption=consumption,
                    is_active=True,
                )
            elif refuel.vehicle == form.instance.vehicle and form.instance.snitch:
                consumption = (refuel.fuel_quantity / (form.instance.snitch - refuel.snitch)) * 100
                FuelConsumption.objects.create(
                    vehicle=refuel.vehicle,
                    gaz_station=form.instance.gaz_station,
                    Controlor_id=self.request.user,
                    driver=refuel.vehicle.driver,
                    consumption=consumption,
                    is_active=True,
                )
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Refuel.objects.select_related("vehicle__gaz_station__Controlor_id").filter(
            vehicle__gaz_station__Controlor_id=self.request.user
        )
```

But I don't know why the queryset method don't gives me only the vehicles set that I want to display in select list.
I'll post the solution if I got one.